# C windows gui font-size change on hmenu

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, resources

I have this menu in my resource file for `WINAPI`, the elements of the menu look so small, is there a way make the font size bigger or change the color of the text? either with adding some code in the main code or changing the resource file..

I have tried `FONT 13, "MS Sans Serif"` but it did not work

```
IDR_MYMENU MENU
BEGIN
FONT 13, "MS Sans Serif"
POPUP "&File"
BEGIN
MENUITEM "&Exit", IDD_FILE_EXIT
END

POPUP "&Stuff"
BEGIN
MENUITEM "&Go", ID_STUFF_GO
MENUITEM "&File Kapat", IDD_FILE_KAPAT
END

END
```

Comment: You have to handle all the painting of your menu to your self i.e. owner drawn control to do so

Comment: Are you running on a high-density display, and have marked the application as DPI-aware, without it actually being DPI-aware?

Comment: @IInspectable Ok I figured it out thanks to your help :) I see you answer a lot of questions, do you code C on windows like I do, or both Linux and Windows platform?